Why nginx doesn't honour the Cache-Control request from client?
I have a cache directive in my nginx balancer without any particular settings.
I see that when I push CTRL-F5 in my browser, all resources are requested with Cache-Control:no-cache headers but nginx still reply with cached content.
Is is by design that nginx honour just backend server cache header and not the client one?
This is the relevatn part of cache config of nginx:
  proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=mycache:100m max_size=500m inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
  proxy_cache_key $host$request_uri;

  proxy_cache mycache;
  add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

The X-Cache-Status values is HIT even if Cache-Control from the client is no-cache
This is the full configuration:
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    log_format cache_st '$remote_addr - $upstream_cache_status [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log cache_st;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    #
    ## Cache
    #
    
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=mycache:100m max_size=500m inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;


    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-cache-purge.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_cache_purge_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-dav-ext.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-echo.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_echo_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-fancyindex.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_fancyindex_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip2.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip2_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-headers-more-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-perl.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-subs-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_subs_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-uploadprogress.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_uploadprogress_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-upstream-fair.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_upstream_fair_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-nchan.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_nchan_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/70-mod-stream-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/70-mod-stream-geoip2.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_geoip2_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/010-mysiteb:
# HTTP

server {
        server_name mysite2 mysiteb mysite3 mysiteb;
    listen 80;  
    include commons/http-location.inc;
}

# BALANCED HAPROXY2 - TCP 81

server {
        server_name mysiteb;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysiteb/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysiteb/privkey.pem;
    include commons/ha-location-2.inc;
}

# BALANCED HAPROXY WEB - TCP 82

server {
        server_name mysite3 mysiteb;
    listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite3/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite3/privkey.pem;
        include commons/ha-location-web.inc;
}

server {
        server_name mysite2;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite2/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite2/privkey.pem;
        include commons/ha-location-web.inc;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/commons/http-location.inc:
        location /.well-known {
                alias /var/www/html/.well-known;
        }
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

# configuration file /etc/nginx/commons/ha-location-2.inc:
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                error_page 502 /502error.html;
        }
        location /ws {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_read_timeout 120;
        }
        location = /502error.html {
                root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }

# configuration file /etc/nginx/commons/ha-location-web.inc:
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                error_page 502 /502error.html;
        proxy_cache mycache;
        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        }
        location = /502error.html {
                root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }

# configuration file /etc/nginx/commons/srvap1-location.inc:
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://srvap1/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                error_page 502 /502error.html;
        }
        location /ws {
                proxy_pass http://srvap1;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_read_timeout 120;
        }
        location = /502error.html {
                root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }

# configuration file /etc/nginx/commons/srvap2-location.inc:
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://srvap2/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                error_page 502 /502error.html;
        }
        location /ws {
                proxy_pass http://srvap2;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_read_timeout 120;
        }
        location = /502error.html {
                root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/030-mysitea:
# HTTP

server {
        server_name mysite1 mysite4 mysite5;
    listen 80;  
    include commons/http-location.inc;
}

# BALANCED HAPROXY - TCP 81

server {
        server_name mysite4;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite4/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite4/privkey.pem;
    include commons/ha-location-2.inc;
}

server {
        server_name mysite5 mysitea;
    listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite5/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite5/privkey.pem;
        include commons/ha-location-web.inc;
}

server {
        server_name mysite1;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite1/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite1/privkey.pem;
        include commons/ha-location-web.inc;
}

# AP1 - TCP 10001

server {
        server_name mysite4;
        listen 10001 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite4/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite4/privkey.pem;
    include commons/srvap1-location.inc;
}

server {
        server_name mysite5 mysitea;
        listen 10001 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite5/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite5/privkey.pem;
        include commons/srvap1-location.inc;
}

server {
        server_name mysite1;
        listen 10001 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite1/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite1/privkey.pem;
        include commons/srvap1-location.inc;
}

# AP2 - TCP 10002

server {
        server_name mysite4;
        listen 10002 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite4/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite4/privkey.pem;
        include commons/srvap2-location.inc;
}

server {
        server_name mysite5 mysitea;
        listen 10002 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite5/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite5/privkey.pem;
        include commons/srvap2-location.inc;
}

server {
        server_name mysite1;
        listen 10002 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite1/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite1/privkey.pem;
        include commons/srvap2-location.inc;
}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
server {

    listen 127.0.0.1:1935;

    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        stub_status;
    }

}


From the documentation: The no-cache request directive asks caches to validate the response with the origin server before reuse. So the proxy can use the cached response as long as it first validates that it's up to date.

The returned header status is HIT. If it is revalidated I expect a REVALIDATED header.

Nginx skip cache for requests based on the proxy_cache_bypass setting. To prevent the request from being taken from the cache when Cache-Control: no-cache is set, you can add the following to the settings:

to http {}, next to proxy_cache_path:
  map $http_cache_control $skip_cache_header {
    default 0;
    no-cache 1;
  }


to site config, next to proxy_cache:
proxy_cache_bypass $skip_cache_header;



Note that this will not update the cached element on the server, and requests without this header will continue to receive data from the old cache.

Thank you. So nginx doesn't chekc cache control header by default?

nginx uses "Cache-Control" from the origin server to determine whether content should be cached. But from the visitor's side, this does not seem to be taken into account unless additionally configured with proxy_cache_bypass.
You can read this article - it describes the caching setup and how it works:
https://blog.nginx.org/blog/nginx-caching-guide
